# JCR SQL2 query for an empty multivalued field

Tags: magnolia, jcr-sql2

In our scenario we have a (multivalued) category field on JCR:node and we want to query all nodes that do not have a current selection. In the JCR viewer the fields value is [] but I can't find any query to select nodes with this condition. We have tries:

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:page] as p WHERE p.[categories]=''
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:page] as p WHERE p.[categories]=[]
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:page] as p WHERE p.[categories] is null
```

But they aren't working or don't select the proper result. How can we write a query selecting these nodes?

Answer (score 1):

From the [JSR 283](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=283):

> **5.10.3 Value Length**
> The length of a value in a single-value property, as defined in §3.6.7 Length of a Value, is returned by `long Property.getLength()`
> Similarly, the method `long[] Property.getLengths()` is used to get an array of the lengths of all the values of a multi-value property.

From the JavaDocs:

```java
    /**
     * Returns an array holding the lengths of the values of this (multi-value)
     * property in bytes where each is individually calculated as described in
     * {@link #getLength()}.
     * <p>
     * Returns a <code>-1</code> in the appropriate position if the
     * implementation cannot determine the length of a value.
     *
     * @return an array of lengths
     * @throws ValueFormatException if this property is single-valued.
     * @throws RepositoryException  if another error occurs.
     */
    public long[] getLengths() throws ValueFormatException, RepositoryException;
```

Unfortunately, this does not make it clear what the result of `LENGTH([multivaluedProperty)]` is in a SQL2 query.

Though, after some manual testing, it seems that the `LENGTH` operand returns some number smaller than 0. Therefore, you could try

`select * from [nt:base] where LENGTH([multivaluedProperty]) < 0`

Let me know whether this works for you :)

Comment: Indeed, it is possible to query empty multivalued fields with LENGTH, but this is not combinable with an additional match condition. What is working is: `SELECT p FROM [mgnl:page] as p WHERE LENGTH(p.[mvProp])<0`
but not: `SELECT p FROM [mgnl:page] as p WHERE LENGTH(p.[mvProp])<0 or p.[mvProp]='foobar'` . The second query causes `javax.jcr.UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException` as he seems to switch to a Lucene query due to the text-search (I guess)